# Singularity containers: adding custom packages to $PATH and pass it to singularity exec

Tags: path, exec, command-line-arguments, singularity-container

I'm in the process of making a singularity container with PLINK v 1.9 (a genetics software, not the PuTTY interface, https://www.cog-genomics.org/plink/1.9/dev) inside it. I'm able to successfully compile the software within the container and I can see the PLINK files and functions when I shell into the container. To make things easier for my end users, I am trying to add the software's main folder to the singularity $PATH so that they can just call plink from the command line, but I'm not able to achieve this.

So far I have tried:

1. Assigning SINGULARITYENV_APPEND_PATH=path/to/plink in the %runscript section of my singularity recipe file.
2. Moving the source code folder for Plink into /usr/local/bin of the Singularity
3. Setting a variable PLINKDIR=/path/to/plink and the export it in the %environment section of my recipe file similar to what they have done [here.](https://github.com/sylabs/singularity/issues/732)

None of these methods work. The only way I can access this package is by spelling out the full path in my singularity exec command.

```
singularity exec test.simg /path/to/plink/plink --version
```

I would like to just run

```
singularity exec test.simg plink --version
```

Contents of my singularity recipe file:

```
    BootStrap: docker
    From: ubuntu:16.04

    %labels
  Plink Version 1.9


%runscript
  # Allows us to run the versions of the packages installed in the post
  # section
  exec plink19 "$@"

%environment
  export SINGULARITYENV_PLINKDIR="/plink-ng-b15c19f/1.9/"

%post
  # Make some directories for storage
  mkdir /new_folder_1 /new_folder_2
  apt-get update
  apt-get -y upgrade

  apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
        software-properties-common \
        build-essential \
        apt-transport-https \
        curl \
        git \
        wget \
        libfreetype6-dev \
        pkg-config \
        python \
        python-dev \
        dh-autoreconf \
        libarchive-dev \
        libatlas-dev \
        libatlas-base-dev \
        zlib1g-dev


  # Install PLINK
  wget https://github.com/chrchang/plink-ng/archive/b15c19f.tar.gz
  tar xvf b15c19f.tar.gz
  cd /plink-ng-b15c19f/1.9/
  ./plink_first_compile
  ln -s plink plink19

%test 
  echo $PLINKDIR
```

The echo statement outputs nothing. How do I add custom packages like this (meaning not installed using apt-get) to the singularity environment so that they can be called from the command line with singularity exec? Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to just add it to your path:

```
%environment
    PATH=$PATH:/path/to/plink/
```

Also, edit your runscript:

```
%runscript
    exec "$@"
```

Then you can run:

```
singularity run test.simg plink --version
```

Answer (score 1):

The first part of your message mentions "so that they can just call plink from the command line, but I'm not able to achieve this." In that case why not just:

```
apt-get install -y plink1.9
```

In your definition file?

And In my case, If I try `singularity exec imgfile.sif plink --version` it obviously doesn't work since you have to call `plink1.9` so: `singularity exec imagfile.sif plink1.9 --version`.