# singularity exec is not recognizing executables in container $PATH (converted micromamba docker image to singularity image)

Tags: docker, path, environment-variables, containers, singularity-container

There is a similar post but this post is regarding building a singularity container: [Singularity containers: adding custom packages to $PATH and pass it to singularity exec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54914587/singularity-containers-adding-custom-packages-to-path-and-pass-it-to-singulari)

I have converted a Docker container to Singularity.

Here's my Dockerfile which adds executables to `micromamba` image:

```
# v2024.1.29
# =================================
FROM mambaorg/micromamba:1.5.6

ARG ENV_NAME

SHELL ["/usr/local/bin/_dockerfile_shell.sh"]

WORKDIR /tmp/

# Data
USER root
RUN mkdir -p /volumes/
RUN mkdir -p /volumes/input
RUN mkdir -p /volumes/output
RUN mkdir -p /volumes/database

# Retrieve VEBA repository
RUN mkdir -p veba/
USER $MAMBA_USER
COPY --chown=$MAMBA_USER:$MAMBA_USER ./install/ veba/install/
COPY --chown=$MAMBA_USER:$MAMBA_USER ./bin/ veba/bin/
COPY --chown=$MAMBA_USER:$MAMBA_USER ./VERSION veba/VERSION
COPY --chown=$MAMBA_USER:$MAMBA_USER ./LICENSE veba/LICENSE

# Install dependencies
RUN micromamba install -y -n base -f veba/install/environments/${ENV_NAME}.yml && \ 
    micromamba clean -a -y -f

# Add environment scripts to environment bin
RUN cp -rf veba/bin/* /opt/conda/bin/ && \
    ln -sf /opt/conda/bin/scripts/*.py /opt/conda/bin/ && \
    ln -sf /opt/conda/bin/scripts/*.r /opt/conda/bin/


ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/local/bin/_entrypoint.sh"]
```

Here's the actual Docker image:
https://hub.docker.com/r/jolespin/veba_binning-prokaryotic/tags

To build the Singularity image, I ran the following:

```
singularity pull containers/veba_binning-prokaryotic__1.5.0.sif docker://jolespin/veba_binning-prokaryotic:1.5.0
```

Here's my script to run singularity using the Docker image:

```
declare -xr SINGULARITY_MODULE='singularitypro/3.9'

module purge
module load "${SINGULARITY_MODULE}"


# Local directories
VEBA_DATABASE=/expanse/projects/jcl110/db/veba/VDB_v6/
LOCAL_WORKING_DIRECTORY=$(pwd)
LOCAL_WORKING_DIRECTORY=$(realpath -m ${LOCAL_WORKING_DIRECTORY})
LOCAL_DATABASE_DIRECTORY=${VEBA_DATABASE} # /path/to/VEBA_DATABASE/
LOCAL_DATABASE_DIRECTORY=$(realpath -m ${LOCAL_DATABASE_DIRECTORY})

# Container directories
CONTAINER_INPUT_DIRECTORY=/volumes/input/
CONTAINER_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=/volumes/output/
CONTAINER_DATABASE_DIRECTORY=/volumes/database/

FASTA=${CONTAINER_INPUT_DIRECTORY}/veba_output/assembly/S1/output/scaffolds.fasta
BAM=${CONTAINER_INPUT_DIRECTORY}/veba_output/assembly/S1/output/mapped.sorted.bam
OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=${CONTAINER_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY}/test_output/
NAME="S1"

SINGULARITY_IMAGE="containers/veba_binning-prokaryotic__1.5.0.sif"
singularity exec \
    --bind ${LOCAL_WORKING_DIRECTORY}:${CONTAINER_INPUT_DIRECTORY},${LOCAL_WORKING_DIRECTORY}:${CONTAINER_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY},${LOCAL_DATABASE_DIRECTORY}:${CONTAINER_DATABASE_DIRECTORY} \
    --contain \
     ${SINGULARITY_IMAGE} \
     binning-prokaryotic.py -f ${FASTA} -b ${BAM} -n ${NAME} -o ${OUTPUT_DIRECTORY} --veba_database ${CONTAINER_DATABASE_DIRECTORY} --skip_maxbin2
```

The error I get is this:

```
FATAL:   "binning-prokaryotic.py": executable file not found in $PATH
```

When I try setting the PATH variable to `/opt/conda/bin/`, it tries to append my working directory for some reason (working directory is `/expanse/projects/jcl110/Test/TestVEBA/`):

```
(base) [jespinoz@exp-15-01 TestVEBA]$ singularity exec -e PATH=/opt/conda/bin/ containers/veba_binning-prokaryotic__1.5.0.sif echo $PATH
FATAL:   could not open image /expanse/projects/jcl110/Test/TestVEBA/PATH=/opt/conda/bin: failed to retrieve path for /expanse/projects/jcl110/Test/TestVEBA/PATH=/opt/conda/bin: lstat /expanse/projects/jcl110/Test/TestVEBA/PATH=: no such file or directory
(base) [jespinoz@exp-15-01 TestVEBA]$ singularity exec -e PATH:/opt/conda/bin/ containers/veba_binning-prokaryotic__1.5.0.sif echo $PATH
FATAL:   could not open image /expanse/projects/jcl110/Test/TestVEBA/PATH:/opt/conda/bin: failed to retrieve path for /expanse/projects/jcl110/Test/TestVEBA/PATH:/opt/conda/bin: lstat /expanse/projects/jcl110/Test/TestVEBA/PATH:: no such file or directory
```

**Can someone help me figure out either how to load the same environment as with Docker run (i.e., adding `/opt/conda/bin/` to `$PATH`) or just setting my `PATH=/opt/conda/bin` and ignore the local executables?**

Comment: What is in `_dockerfile_shell.sh` and `_entrypoint.sh`?  I suspect an `exec`-type command won't go through either of these scripts.  Setting `ENV PATH=...` in the Dockerfile might resolve both of the issues you show (the second definitely looks unusual).  If you need to use an extended command like at the end of the script, and the main goal of your program is to read and write host files, you also may find it easier to run without a container.

Comment: My work around was to use `"export PATH=/usr/bin/:/opt/conda/bin/; export CONDA_PREFIX=/opt/conda/; binning-prokaryotic.py ...rest-of-the-command..."`

Answer (score 0):

For other people struggling with this: singularity exec won't run the entrypoint script that activates the base conda environment. The way I got around this was to call the entrypoint script before my executable command ([suggested for apptainer in micromamba base image docs](https://micromamba-docker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#how-can-i-use-a-mambaorg-micromamba-based-image-with-apptainer)):

```
/usr/local/bin/_entrypoint.sh myexecutable.py -opts
```